# Matrix equation $Ax=b$ with variable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-equations

"Let a be an arbitrary real number. A matrix A and a vector b is given by $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & a-1 & a & 0 \\ 0 & a & a-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \text{ and } \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$$

**Find the value of a for which the matrix equation $A \cdot x = b$ has the the solution $$x= \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -2 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} + t \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, t \in \mathbb{R}$$**
"

I am not really sure how this can be approached.

Comment: One way (the direct, obvious way) is to calculate $Ax$ with the given $x$, set it equal to $b$ and find which $a$ makes them equal. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Alex5207 If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Comment: @gimusi - I can't find a "Solved" button anywhere - Can you help?

Comment: @Alex5207 take a look here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23001/how-to-mark-that-a-question-has-been-solved

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

One possible way is to let $t=0$ to obtain a particular solution $x_0$.

Write out the matrix product $Ax_0$ and equate it to $b$.

You can then solve for $a$ since we will get **linear** equation in $a$.

After which verify that we can obtain the solution.

Alternative method to solve for $a$ is to note that $[0,1,1,0]^T$ is in the nullspace, again, you will get a linear equation in $a$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. If I let $t=0$ then I have the equation $$Ax=b \Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -2a+2 \\ -2a \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$$ Which means we get $$-2a+2=1 \text{ and } -2a=-1 \Rightarrow a=\frac{1}{2}$$. Now haven't we only shown that $a= \frac{1}{2}$ satifies the equation when $t=0$? How does it show that a is a solution for $t \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Now that you have your $a$, you can solve linear system as usual right? You can check the nullity  of $A$. Check that $[0,1,1,0]$ is in the nullspace.

Answer (score 0):

To satisfy the given condition it,s necessary that the vector multiplied by $t$ belong to the Null Space or Ker(A), thus

$$A \ \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

that gives you the correct value for a.

Finally check that the given solution work for the value of $a$ that you find.